# Display Image from another website on Django template

Tags: django, database, python-3.x

I'm here wondering over one problem since 2 days and still not getting the solution.
The problem is, I have one website URL e.g. "www.something.org/abc/xyz/". On this website there is a list of URLs which contains some images in JPG format.  This URLs are like e.g."2019_01_03_11_12_12_..>" and when I click it, it opens as "www.something.org/abc/xyz/2019_01_03_11_12_12_648626_155_72_6372_6835.jpg". I also want to store these Image Name values separately in database models with certain fields like FacultyID, CourseID, Datetime and likewise. Image must will be stored on server or some other location. Now what I have to do is, I have to display these images from the website on my Django Template. I tried several approaches for doing this. First I tried to scrape this website data and stored it in textfile on my local machine. But after that I din get how to use this data to display images.

Now please help me out to find the proper approach of this problem in Django- Python. Forget my approach and suggest me something which carry out the results.

I'm waiting for the answers.  Please help and get me out of this.

Comment: Can you post at least one complete URL of image? Because, normally you just need pass the var to view and execute like  `{{ my_image_url_var }}`. if you want store the data on Database, you will need parse the info and store... the complete url is `2019_01_03_11_12_12_` or is like `https://..... 2019_01_03_11_12_12_.jpg`?

Comment: "www.something.org/abc/xyz/2019_01_03_11_12_12_648626_155_72_6372_6835.jpg" this is the complete URL of the image. Anything else is needed or should I elaborate the problem more?

Answer (score 0):

Considering probably you already read the Django basic tutorial, I`ll not explain all the basics... if you just need parse those infos and show on view, you will need the basics of Django tutorial about layout... I'll not explain all about for the sake of brevity...

if you do not read yet, please, read this tutorial on Django docs:
[Writing your first Django app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial01/)

But you will need do something like this:

```
def my_view(request):
    return render("my_view_name.html", {
        "images":[... array of images ...]
    })
```

And on view do something like this:

```
{% for each image on images %}
    {{ image.url }}
{% end foreach %}
```

This part of tutorial is very very simple.

About parse the URL to extract infos, you can use an function like this:

```
import datetime

image_url = "https://www.myawesome.url/2019_01_03_11_12_12_648626_155_72_6372_6835.jpg"

def extract_infos(url):

  __cleaned_url = url.replace("https://www.myawesome.url/", "").replace(".jpg", "")
  __infos = __cleaned_url.split('_')
  return {
    "datetime": datetime.datetime.strptime(
      "{}-{}-{} {}:{}:{}".format(
        __infos[0], __infos[1], __infos[2], __infos[3], __infos[4], __infos[5]
        ), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
    "id": __infos[6],
    "extra": [__infos[7], __infos[8], __infos[9], __infos[10]]
  }

print(extract_infos(image_url))
# will print this
# {'datetime': datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 3, 11, 12, 12), 'id': '648626', 'extra': ['155', '72', '6372', '6835']}
```

With this function, now, you can create your Django model and save it... As I don't know exactly what each number is, I created an small pattern called `id` and `extra` whit a small array with other numbers... but you can rewrite the function `extract_infos` to return an array exactly as you need.

Comment: Thank You so much for the help! I 'll try this solution.

Comment: Hope it helps you @anonymous